# Simple Lightweight php controller

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently developing on a professional basis in PHP, noteably cakephp. I haven't spend much time in in the realm of procedural php, hence why I'm here

I have a college project with an Arduino board, where I need to interact via web browser with the on board API, and have a simple button interface driving it. I intend to install a simple project on the webserver and make two calls to the api.

My scenario is this:
Post form form either button, Controller evaluates the button press, creates a GET request for the API, and redirects to a certain page. 
I can easily do this in cake, but I don't see the need to install a chunky framework for such a tiny, single page single controller application.

Is there a lightweight solution available to accommodate this, or would I be better off with just a single php page making the requests via ajax and updating the page content with jquery or something like that

Comment: Just use vanilla PHP and do a cURL request to the api. If you don't need the bloat of a framework don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a framework (maybe you see this increasing in size over the next few years) then look at something like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)

It is pretty simple to pick up and basically allows simple routing and allows for a simple REST API to be setup.

Otherwise you can just handle this with a single PHP files:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       //jquery here if you want to do it async

       $(form).submit(function(e) {

            $.post('/location/of/script.php, serialize(form), function(data) {
                 //do stuff with data
            }
       }
   });
</script>

<!-- HTML CODE GOES HERE -->
```

HTML code for form & button:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```